# Single Sign on with personal Microsoft account doesn't work in registered app in Azure

Tags: azure, active-directory, passport-azure-ad

We registered an app in Azure with our corporate account.
We've set it as a web-app type, and set the signInAudience to `AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount`

It works when we sign into our web-app with a corporate account, but when we use a personal microsoft account with hotmail address, we get the following message:

```
AADSTS50020: User account '*********@hotmail.com' from identity provider 'live.com' does not exist in tenant '*********' and cannot access the application '******'(***-api) in that tenant. The account needs to be added as an external user in the tenant first. Sign out and sign in again with a different Azure Active Directory user account.
```

We double checked all settings and they look valid. We've ran out of ideas
Here's a version of our manifest:

```
{
    "id": "**********",
    "acceptMappedClaims": null,
    "accessTokenAcceptedVersion": 2,
    "addIns": [],
    "allowPublicClient": null,
    "appId": "*********",
    "appRoles": [],
    "oauth2AllowUrlPathMatching": false,
    "createdDateTime": "2020-08-04T14:32:25Z",
    "groupMembershipClaims": "None",
    "identifierUris": [
        "https://***.company.be"
    ],
    "informationalUrls": {
        "termsOfService": "https://www.company.be/legals/gebruiksvoorwaarden",
        "support": null,
        "privacy": "https://www.company.be/legals/privacy",
        "marketing": null
    },
    "keyCredentials": [],
    "knownClientApplications": [],
    "logoUrl": "https://secure.aadcdn.microsoftonline-p.com/...",
    "logoutUrl": null,
    "name": "***-api",
    "oauth2AllowIdTokenImplicitFlow": true,
    "oauth2AllowImplicitFlow": false,
    "oauth2Permissions": [],
    "oauth2RequirePostResponse": false,
    "optionalClaims": {
        "idToken": [
            {
                "name": "email",
                "source": null,
                "essential": false,
                "additionalProperties": []
            },
            {
                "name": "family_name",
                "source": null,
                "essential": false,
                "additionalProperties": []
            },
            {
                "name": "given_name",
                "source": null,
                "essential": false,
                "additionalProperties": []
            }
        ],
        "accessToken": [],
        "saml2Token": []
    },
    "orgRestrictions": [],
    "parentalControlSettings": {
        "countriesBlockedForMinors": [],
        "legalAgeGroupRule": "Allow"
    },
    "passwordCredentials": [
        {
            "customKeyIdentifier": null,
            "endDate": "2299-12-30T23:00:00Z",
            "keyId": "**********",
            "startDate": "2020-08-04T14:47:56.759Z",
            "value": null,
            "createdOn": "2020-08-04T14:47:58.647043Z",
            "hint": "gIh",
            "displayName": "*****-api clientSecret"
        }
    ],
    "preAuthorizedApplications": [],
    "publisherDomain": "company.be",
    "replyUrlsWithType": [
        {
            "url": "http://localhost:3000/link/microsoft/callback",
            "type": "Web"
        },
        {
            "url": "https://api.copmpany.be/link/microsoft/callback",
            "type": "Web"
        },
        {
            "url": "https://api.copmpany.be/auth/microsoft/callback",
            "type": "Web"
        },
        {
            "url": "https://api.staging.copmpany.be/link/microsoft/callback",
            "type": "Web"
        },
        {
            "url": "https://api.staging.copmpany.be/auth/microsoft/callback",
            "type": "Web"
        },
        {
            "url": "http://localhost:3000/auth/microsoft/callback",
            "type": "Web"
        }
    ],
    "requiredResourceAccess": [
        {
            "resourceAppId": "***",
            "resourceAccess": [
                {
                    "id": "****",
                    "type": "Scope"
                },
                {
                    "id": "***",
                    "type": "Scope"
                },
                {
                    "id": "***",
                    "type": "Scope"
                },
                {
                    "id": "***",
                    "type": "Scope"
                },
                {
                    "id": "***",
                    "type": "Scope"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "samlMetadataUrl": null,
    "signInUrl": "https://www.company.be",
    "signInAudience": "AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount",
    "tags": [
        "webApp",
        "notApiConsumer"
    ],
    "tokenEncryptionKeyId": null,
    "verifiedPublisher": {
        "displayName": null,
        "verifiedPublisherId": null,
        "addedDateTime": null
    }
}
```

Comment: This also applies to error:
AADSTS500200: User account '<snip>' is a personal Microsoft account. Personal Microsoft accounts are not supported for this application unless explicitly invited to an organization. Try signing out and signing back in with an organizational account.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to [Sarthak's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63530237/12980385) if your business scenario doesn't need to access your tenant's resource like call MS Graph API for your tenant, You could change your authority Uri to common endpoint which supports MSA without inviting into tenant. Please refer the documentation on for the [authority endpoints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-protocols-oidc#fetch-the-openid-connect-metadata-document). Depending upon your business scenario, choose your solution.

Comment: @Ernie i was trying to integrate MSF OIDC to AWS cognito userpool. Created new app registration and in Azure AD with `"signInAudience": "AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount" and "issuer": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0"` and other settings. When i try to login with work or personal MSF account it's throwing `"invalid_request" error with description "Bad id_token issuer"`. If i replace the tenant_id "common" in issuer with specific tenant_id(9188040d-6c67-4c5b-b112-36a304b66dad for example-personal MSF) then the flow is working as expected. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Sign in option `AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount` only works with v2.0. Hence, the authority URL should be this:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0
```

In addition to that, for multitenant applications, `ValidateIssuer` option should be disabled. You can do that in this way:

```
auth.AddOpenIdConnect(authScheme, displayName, options =>
{
   options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateIssuer = false;
)};
```

Answer (score 0):

From your manifest file I can see that your app is already registered as multi-tenant, so no need to change any settings there.

The user should be invited before we sign or connect with our azure active directory as an external user, follow the below steps:

1. Visit here https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_AAD_IAM/UsersManagementMenuBlade/MsGraphUsers
2. Invite as a guest user
3. Then the invited user will get an invitation, accept that first.
4. Retry to access the web app.
5. Definitely it would work.

Comment: Thx for your answer! We have thousands of users that we want to connect. We can't add them all and invite them all. We just want a single-sign-on experience were users can access our web-app and re-use their microsoft credentials, regardless from which tenant or personal account they belong to.

Answer (score -1):

The app should be registered as multi-tenant for this to work.